# sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected IDENT

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

Getting this error with sphinx 2

```
sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting CONST_INT or CONST_FLOAT or '-' near 'WI AND published = 1 AND sphinx_deleted = 0 LIMIT 0, 10; SHOW META'
```

#### index.html.erb

error is being thrown in the template at the line of a partial collection: @posts_by_state, but two other instances of the same partial are working great. The State sort is what is throwing it off.

#### posts_controller.rb

```
@posts_by_state = Post.search(params[:search], with: { state: current_user.state, published: true }, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

#### post_index.rb

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :post, :with => :active_record do
  indexes :title, as: :post_title
  indexes :desc, as: :description
  indexes tags(:name), as: :tag_name
  #indexes happening_on, sortable: true
  #has author_id, published_at
  has published_at
  has last_touched
  has state
  has published

  set_property:field_weights => {
    :post_title => 5,
    :description => 1,
    :tag_name => 10
  }
end
```

Comment: Yes, thought that might be the problem, but didn't know the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String attributes in Sphinx can only be used for sorting - not filtering, not grouping - and so your options to work around this are as follows:

- Pull it out into an associated model (State or PostState, perhaps?), and then filter by the foreign key integer instead.
- Store that value as a field instead, and use :conditions instead of :with.
- Hack around it with [CRC32 values](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/common_issues.html#string_filters).

I highly recommend the first of these options (I'd argue it's cleaner, accurate), but it's up to you.

Comment: FYI, Sphinx 2.0.1 "added support for sorting and grouping on string attributes" and 2.2.3 added "filtering over string attributes" http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html